# Laravel - failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, permission-denied

I'm trying to install a laravel app on digital ocean. When I run the command `php artisan migrate --seed` I'm getting the following error when it reaches one of the seeders:

```
 The stream or file "/var/www/test.mysite.com/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I followed the DO tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) and added the following permissions:

```
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/test.mysite.com/storage
sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/test.mysite.com/bootstrap/cache
```

So why is it still throwing the permission denied error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix. I needed to give my self (the logged in ssh user) ownership of the directory and the webser as follows:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.mysite.com
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/test.mysite.com/storage /var/www/test.mysite.com/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/test.mysite.com/storage /var/www/test.mysite.com/bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Just know that if the read/write permissions aren't correct and your web server runs as a different user, you'll run into issues when a web request tries to write to the log.

Comment: @aynber see update which would fix the web server write issue

Answer (score 4):

Run this command for storage permission

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/
```

Also you can set nginx permissive mode

```
semanage permissive -a httpd_t
```

The nginx permissive mode working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Go your project root directory and run this command**

```
chmod -R 777 storage/
```

**If there for bootstrap cache try this**

```
chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set security settings as follows

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

If default port(80/tcp) is changed run the following command in addition.

```
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my side it is about `WWWUSER` and `WWWGROUP` env variables. In local env these values are `1000`. I copied all .env files to server and then I can't able to write a file in docker (or sail). Because server's uuid and guid are different. You must set these correctly in .env file, otherwise docker can not able to write a file in project (log, session etc...).

Solution steps:

1- Find correct uuid and guid:

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep $(whoami)
exampleuser:x:1007:1008::/home/exampleuser:/bin/bash
```

2- The column order is like that: `[username]:[password]:[UUID]:[GUID]` So 1007 is uuid, 1008 is guid. Then we must set these values in .env file.

```
WWWUSER=1007
WWWGROUP=1008
```

3- Rebuild and restart containers. Actually I don't know is this step necessary but I strongly suggest make it.

```
sail stop
sail build --no-cache
sail down
sail up -d
```

After that you can run whatever you want with `sail` command. For example:

```
sail composer install
sail artisan key:generate
sail artisan cache:clear
sail artisan [any command which you want to execute]
```

Edit: Making writable all folders is not a good idea. Folders permissions must be 755 or 750. If you set them 777 then other shared hostings can access to your files. This is a vulnerable. If you did this then don't forget to set folder permissions to 750 or 755. `chmod -R 750 storage`